# std::cout << Predicting the automatic field width in displayed for an arbitrary double

Tags: c++

I'm displaying a large number of doubles on the console, and I would like to know in advance how many decimal places std::cout will decide to display for a given double. This is basically so I can make it look pretty in the console.
e.g. (pseudo-code)

```
feild_width = find_maximum_display_precision_that_cout_will_use( whole_set_of_doubles );
...
// Every cout statement:
std::cout << std::setw( feild_width ) << double_from_the_set << std::endl;
```

I figure cout "guesses"? a good precision to display based on the double. For example, it seems to display

```
std::cout << sqrt(2) << std::endl;
```

as 1.41421, but also

```
std::cout << (sqrt(0.5)*sqrt(0.5) + sqrt(1.5)*sqrt(1.5)) << std::endl;
```

as 2 (rather than 2.000000000000?????? or 1.99999999?????). Well, maybe this calculates to exactly 2.0, but I don't think that `sqrt(2)` will calculate to exactly 1.41421, so std::cout has to make some decision about how many decimal places to display at some point, right?

Anyway possible to predict this to formulate a `find_maximum_display_precision...()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you are mixing precision and width, which are two different things. 
Other answers concentrate on precision, but the given precision is the maximum, not a minimum of displayed digits. It does not pad trailing zeros, if not `ios::fixed` or `ios::scientific` is set.

Here is a solution to determine the number of characters used for output, including sign and powers of 10:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

size_t max_width(const std::vector<double>& v)
{
  size_t max = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::ostringstream out;
    // optional: set precision, width, etc. to the same as in std::cout
    out << v[i];
    size_t length = out.str().size();
    if (length > max) max = length;
  }
  return max;
}
```

Comment: So, I guess I need to try it as see. Pity there isn't some standard part of the library which would tell you, eh...

Comment: @Bingo: §27 in C++ standard is a tedious read. Try §21.4 in [Stroustrup, 3rd Edition, p.628]. He says: The general format **lets the implementation choose** a format that presents a value in the style theat best preserves the values in the space available. The precision specifies the maximum number of digits. It corresponds to `printf()`'s `%g`. So when you insist the on fixed format, follow the advice @Martin gave.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the fixed iomanip.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/

```
double d = 10/3;

std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << std::fixed << d << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes C++ I/O bites. Making pretty output is one of those sometimes. The C printf family is easier to control, more understandable, more terse, and isn't plagued with those truly awful ios:: global variables. If you need to use C++ output for other reasons, you can always sprintf/snprintf to a string buffer and then print that using the << to stream operator. IMHO, If you don't need to use C++ output, don't. It is ugly and verbose.

Comment: Yeah, they both seem ugly in unique ways. printf style is easier to prettyficate, but not as neat when you have to manage that string buffer unnecessarily. Thanks for the answer though, or rather, reading the question. :P

Answer (score 0):

std::cout::precision(); use it to determine precision 
example :

```
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>

int main (void) 
{

   double x = 3.1415927

   std::cout << "Pi is " << std::setprecision(4) << x << std::endl;
   return 1;
}
```

This would display:

```
Pi is 3.142
```

---

This link also includes explanation  for std::cout::precision();
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/